# No/incorrect rendering of background-color for vector tiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

I'm trying out vector tiles in QGIS:
[image: QGIS screenshot]

It works great, with one exception: the background-color defined in the [style](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/3e1a00aeae81496587988075fe529f71/resources/styles/root.json?f=pjson) should be #F2EFE9, but in QGIS, it just renders as white. You can see the difference here:
[image: difference between QGIS and ESRI online]
Left is QGIS, continents are white, right is the online vector tiles map from ESRI, showing the continents in #F2EFE9

I'm having the same issue (background rendering as white instead of the color defined in the style) with Maptiler vector tiles in QGIS

Is this a bug and should I register it in the QGIS repository on Github?

Comment: Is it just the background-color not being applied, or is it all the styling

Comment: Just the background-color, the other styling is fine.